# OOP - Non-standard syntax, use & to create a pointer to member (Visual Studio C++)

Tags: c++, oop, do-while

I have had problems with my program, for some reason Visual Studio shows the following message when I compile:

```
'opuntia::menu': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to the member
```

I've seen that this error is related to omitting some `()`, but I think this is not the case. Any ideas to fix this problem?

opuntia.h

```
#pragma once

class opuntia{
public:
    int op;
    void menu();

};
```

opuntia.cpp

```
#include "opuntia.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void opuntia::menu() {
    do {
        cout << "\n \t OPUNTIA: CUIDADO DE AGAVÁCEAS, CACTÁCEAS Y CRASULÁCEAS" << endl;
        cout << "\t Registra tu planta y planea sus cuidados \n" << endl;
        cout << "\t 1. Registro" << endl;
        cout << "\t 2. Registro manual" << endl;
        cout << "\t 3. Miscelánea" << endl;
        cout << "\t 0. Salir \n" << endl;
        cin >> op;
        cin.ignore();

        switch (op) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Registro" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Registro manual" << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Miscelánea" << endl;
            break;
        case 0:
            cout << "Goodbye" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Elige una opción válida" << endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (menu != 0);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include "opuntia.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish");

    opuntia ejecutar;
    ejecutar.menu();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is `menu` here `while (menu != 0)`?

Comment: I’ll bet you could remove almost all of that code and still show the problem. After you’ve got it down to the smallest example you can come up with that shows the problem, it you still don’t see what’s wrong, post what you have.

Comment: `while (menu != 0);` is nonsense when `menu` is a member function (and it is, because that the very member function you're in).

Answer (score 1):

Within the member function menu in the condition of the do-while statement

```
 do {
     //...
 } while (menu != 0);
```

you are using the name of the member function `menu`. It seems you mean

```
 do {
     //...
 } while (op != 0);
```